# How to create an autofill field in Google Forms from a csv file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a csv file with the list of world countries and using Form Ranger I have imported it to Google Forms and displayed as a multiple choice.

As there are 195 countries (2020), the list gets very long and I feel better than a multiple choice would be field that autocomplete from the csv when the user starts typing.

Can this be done?

Comment: AFAIK, No, It can't be done

Comment: I found this which is somewhat in that direction but still not quite there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3AL7ASI_cA

Comment: Explain "quite not there"

Comment: I am looking for an autocomplete field, the video is about a drop down list

Comment: Yes. There's no autocomplete support for Google forms. Right? If you can't do something manually, there's no way you can do it programmatically.

Comment: You can request this feature from the `?` button located at the bottom-left side of the screen and then `Report a problem`